# Bluetooth is scanning for devices but no device is displaying

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I turned the Bluetooth on but it is infinitely scanning for devices.
[image: It displays no results like this.]

Here is some information about my Ubuntu 20.04.6:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:2852 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 30fa:0300  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 22d9:2766 realme 真我GT 大师探索版
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth 
[    3.003902] usb 3-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    4.002429] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.002445] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.002450] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.002451] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.002453] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.008862] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[    4.008864] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000a, hci ver 000b
[    4.008865] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
[    5.309217] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.309219] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.309226] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   22.732049] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.732057] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.732062] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  133.314888] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[  137.834175] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[  269.784718] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[  440.650122] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000002944b2eb failed to resubmit (2)
[  466.182303] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[  466.182309] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000a, hci ver 000b
[  466.182311] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
[  477.765333] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000077dd4af failed to resubmit (2)
[  481.697712] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[  481.697716] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000a, hci ver 000b
[  481.697718] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
[  489.406544] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 1015.063308] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command


~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-12-28 12:18:50 CST; 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7287 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18329)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7287 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx bluetoothd[7287]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx bluetoothd[7287]: Starting SDP server
12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx bluetoothd[7287]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx bluetoothd[7287]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.85 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
12月 28 12:18:50 sharve-HP-Pavilion-Aero-Laptop-13-be0xxx bluetoothd[7287]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.85 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```